# How to tell the difference between distros when distro hopping

Tags: grub2, 20.04, desktop-environments

I recently setup distro hopping (n distros sharing the same home), with both distros being Ubuntu 20.04. As they share all ui configuration, it is a little hard to know which side of the computer I have grubbed into. I was wondering how others have tackled this? My tentative plan is to run a script at login that changes the background based on hostname, but didn't know if there were any other or better options.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the hostname wallpaper script solution is as good as it's going to get, since any configuration will just be shared across systems. Also if you want here's how to set wallpaper from CLI in Gnome: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/username/image.png`.

Comment: @ashvatthama that actually helps a lot. I was just going to point gnome to a particular file and change the file but that works better

Comment: I long ago liked the idea of sharing home between my dual boot system (this box is currently *groovy* & 18.04/*bionic*), however be aware when versions differ (currently yours do not) problems can occur (for me, I started using a feature to newer feature to sort/color email; the older version couldn't handle the data change & thus ignored those emails... about 40% of my email became invisible to the older release; in another case it lost access to all data).. These problems won't occur with same versions of software, but be aware of pitfalls... (I install more than one desktop in preference)